# Wpf create dynamic table using Itemsources

Tags: c#, wpf, itemscontrol

I managed to create this table using stackpanels and itemscontrols but it takes ages to load after all. In my ViewModel I have a list of hotels which contain rooms. Every room for every day in a range I set can be booked or not etc. So in my View I need to show the this data in a dynamic table (?) where every row will have each hotel then each hotel will have each room, then columns of months  and every date etc as you can see in picture. At last every square is a button with a tool-tip showing more info and if clicked it has to select the row and column. I managed to do this for the column by setting the bolder color. Everything works but I thing this is not a correct implementation and it also needs to much time to render.

Here is my output

[image]

and the xaml

```
                   <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                BorderThickness="1"
                                Visibility="{Binding IsPlanVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                    <Border Width="150"
                                            BorderBrush="Black"
                                            BorderThickness="0,0,0,1">
                                        <TextBlock Text="Hotel"
                                                   Margin="5,0"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                            Width="110"
                                            BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
                                        <TextBlock Text="RoomType" Margin="5"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Months}">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <!--<Border>-->
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"
                                                            Background="{Binding Background}">
                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                               MinHeight="30"
                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Days }">
                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                        Width="22"
                                                                        BorderThickness="0,1,1,1">
                                                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                                                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                                                        <ToggleButton Width="22"
                                                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                                      IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                                                                      Command="{Binding DataContext.ToggleDateCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Date}">
                                                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Date, StringFormat='{}{0:dd}' }"
                                                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                                                        </ToggleButton>
                                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                                </Border>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl>

                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <!--</Border>-->
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <!--Hotels Item Control-->
                                <!--Each Row-->
                                <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1"
                                              Margin="0,-1,0,0"
                                              HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                              VerticalAlignment="Top"
                                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredPlanList}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="Top">
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                    <!--Each Hotel-->
                                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                            Width="150"
                                                            BorderThickness="0,1,0,0"
                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"
                                                                   Padding="5,0,0,0"
                                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                    </Border>
                                                    <!--Rooms Row-->
                                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Rooms}"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
                                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                            <DataTemplate>
                                                                <!--Each Room Row-->
                                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                                    <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                            Width="109"
                                                                            BorderThickness="1,1,0,0"
                                                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RoomType }"
                                                                                   Margin="0,1"
                                                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                                                                    </Border>
                                                                    <!--Rectangles ItemSource-->
                                                                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding BookedInfoList}"
                                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                                                                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                                            <DataTemplate>

                                                                                <Button Background="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BConverter}}"
                                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                                                        Width="22"
                                                                                        ToolTipService.IsEnabled="{Binding Reservation,Converter={StaticResource ToolTipVis}}"
                                                                                        BorderBrush="{Binding IsDateSelected,Converter={StaticResource BoolToBorderColorConverter}}"
                                                                                        BorderThickness="1,0,0,1">
                                                                                    <Button.InputBindings>
                                                                                        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                                                                                                      Command="{  Binding DataContext.ViewReservationCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}"
                                                                                                      CommandParameter="{Binding Reservation}" />
                                                                                    </Button.InputBindings>
                                                                                    <Button.ToolTip>
                                                                                        <StackPanel>
                                                                                            <Grid Margin="0,0,0,5"
                                                                                                  DataContext="{Binding Reservation}">
                                                                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="170" />
                                                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
                                                                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                                                <!--Row 0-->
                                                                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                                                                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                                                                        BorderThickness="1">
                                                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Dates}"
                                                                                                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                                                               Margin="5,0" />
                                                                                                </Border>
                                                                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                                                        Grid.Row="0"
                                                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                                                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                                                                                        BorderThickness="0,1,1,1"></Border>
                                                                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                                                                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                                                                        BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
                                                                                                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0"
                                                                                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                                                               Text="{Binding Room.Hotel}" />
                                                                                                </Border>
                                                                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                                                        Grid.Row="1"
                                                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                                                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                                                                                        BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
                                                                                                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0"
                                                                                                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                                                               Text="{Binding Room.RoomType}" />
                                                                                                </Border>
                                                                                                <!--Row 2-->
                                                                                                <Border BorderBrush="Black"
                                                                                                        Grid.Row="2"
                                                                                                        Grid.Column="0"
                                                                                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                                                                        Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                                                                                        BorderThickness="1,0,1,1">
                                                                                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Names}"
                                                                                                               Margin="5,0"
                                                                                                               FontSize="10"
                                                                                                               HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                                                                                                </Border>
                                                                                            </Grid>
                                                                                        </StackPanel>
                                                                                    </Button.ToolTip>
                                                                                </Button>
                                                                                <!--</Border>
                                                                                </Border>-->
                                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                                    </ItemsControl>
                                                                </StackPanel>
                                                            </DataTemplate>
                                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                            </DataTemplate>
                                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Designing UI controls is **hard**. Like, ***really hard***. Your implementation is going to be slow no matter what, as you're making a complex control out of other controls. To do this fast you'd need create your own control from scratch. Possibly using Direct2d to be as fast as possible. This will be an enormous task, one that a developer without expertise in the creation of UI controls might not be able to accomplish in any reasonable time. Or, you might want to redesign to show parts of what you need rather than everything at once.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, sure it is hard, I tried many things like templated column headers but it seems impossible to achieve what i need.  I will try to create my own control but  I'm afraid that it would not be much faster than this.